# Deleting a 3GB table took over two hours on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, xwiki

As posted on another forum, when [upgrading XWiki from v7.0.1 to v13.10.9](https://forum.xwiki.org/t/xwiki-v13-10-9-stuck-on-initialing-12-after-acquired-change-log-lock/10998/8?u=1780yz), a non-critical database table `xwikistatsvisit`, for the user visiting statistics, was preventing the after-upgrade migrations. It contained over seven million records and sized 3GB in total. As a workaround, we had to delete all records in the table, but the SQL command `delete from table xwikistatsvisit` took over two hours.

I have verified from ER diagram that the table is stand-alone without any foreign key referring to or from other tables. And the database is MariaDB v10.9.2 installed on the same host.

The host under test is a medium virtual machine with SSD, 4 CPUs of Intel i9 and 8GB of RAM, running MariaDB v10.9.2. Also, the hypervisor needs to enable “PAE/NX” and “Nested VT-x/ADM-V” for higher performance; otherwise, the computing task will get stuck forever.

**My Questions:**

Why the SQL command took so long? Is there any way to proceed faster? E.g. disabling the keys and restrictions, etc.; but I am unfamiliar with this area.

I will highly appreciate any hints or suggestions.

**The definition of the table `xwikistatsvisit`:**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `xwikistatsvisit`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xwikistatsvisit`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `xwikistatsvisit` (
  `XWV_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `XWV_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `XWV_CLASSNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_IP` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `XWV_USER_AGENT` longtext NOT NULL,
  `XWV_COOKIE` longtext NOT NULL,
  `XWV_UNIQUE_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `XWV_PAGE_VIEWS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_PAGE_SAVES` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_DOWNLOADS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_START_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `XWV_END_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`XWV_ID`),
  KEY `XWVS_END_DATE` (`XWV_END_DATE`),
  KEY `XWVS_UNIQUE_ID` (`XWV_UNIQUE_ID`),
  KEY `XWVS_PAGE_VIEWS` (`XWV_PAGE_VIEWS`),
  KEY `XWVS_START_DATE` (`XWV_START_DATE`),
  KEY `XWVS_NAME` (`XWV_NAME`),
  KEY `XWVS_PAGE_SAVES` (`XWV_PAGE_SAVES`),
  KEY `XWVS_DOWNLOADS` (`XWV_DOWNLOADS`),
  KEY `XWVS_IP` (`XWV_IP`),
  KEY `xwv_user_agent` (`XWV_USER_AGENT`(255)),
  KEY `xwv_classname` (`XWV_CLASSNAME`),
  KEY `xwv_number` (`XWV_NUMBER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Maybe `TRUNCATE TABLE xwikistatsvisit` next time..?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @AKX, and I will test and verify tomorrow during the work day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DELETE` command deletes all the matching rows one at a time. If you want to delete all the records from such a big table, `TRUNCATE` should be a lot faster, since it empties the full table at once.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE xwikistatsvisit;
```

[Difference between DELETE and TRUNCATE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-delete-and-truncate/).

Comment: Yes, I have tested and verified. Starting with the same data, the SQL command `truncate table xwikistatsvisit;` finished instantly.